# Datatables: CSS odd/even styling while ignoring nested drill down table

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I'm using the Datatables plugin, and with that I'm using two columns for drilling down. I have odd/even css styling, and the problem is that as soon as I expand the nested table(i.e. expand drill down columns), the formatting for odd/even is thrown off, as it now starts applying to the drill down rows.

I actually have my drill down tables in an entirely different class than the rest of the table, so they have their own color all together.

The first cell in each row has an image, when clicked it calls the datatables fnOpen function and then the nested table expands.

Not sure what parts of the code would help, so if I need to anything please let me know. 
As far as the css:

```
.expTable { /*Expanding Table*/
    background-color: rgba(135,0,168,1);
    color: white;
}
/*Main Table*/
#pastMsgs tr:nth-child(odd)  { 
     background-color: #707070;
}

#pastMsgs tr:nth-child(even)  { 
     background-color: rgba(204,204,204,0.3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed to revise this whole answer...I completely missed this.

```
#tableid tbody tr.even {
}

#tableid tbody tr.odd {
}
```

Using this will ignore the drill down row.